# Is it possible to use gedit on a remote file with root permissions?

Tags: permissions, root, gedit, remote

As titled, I'd like to open (and edit) remote text files with root permissions using the local text editor (gedit)

I know about `nautilus-admin`, but it doesn't seem to work, unfortunately

Comment: One way is you can use SFTP in Nautilus to connect to the remote host or you can mount the remote directory in the local machine with e.g. SSHFS and use `root` as the connect user in both … `root` has to be enabled on the remote host.

Comment: Please re-evaluate this idea. It is very bad. What you should do is put those files in a personal directory, edit those and have the system copy them over (what that copy also makes a backup  of the previous version) Your method will break your system at some point. copy/paste from the web for instance could have it add invisible chars.

Comment: Ok, I guess I will